# What is the best way to show an image (which is in local machine) in picturebox

Tags: asp.net, filepath

I'm working on a project in ASP.NET but I'm stucked in this case;

I have ten thousands of images in local machine. I need to show them in the picturebox in ASP.Net. I can not copy all images to web appliation folder. So I have to give the file path like

> \\server\something\something.jpg

But it doesnt work of course.

I found some solutions but they are not so clear, so I didnt manage to success.

So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In IIS, define a virtual sub-directory in your site, with directory's physical location being `\\server\something`. Then you will be able to specify image virtual url as `~/something.jpg`.
2. Use code-behind to return images (`aspx` page or `ashx` handler) - then, with enough permissions given to IIS user, the web application will read the required image and put it in response stream.